# Why is my new div affecting the div before it?

Tags: html, css

So I am using the CSS grid for a blog example and have made one box (About Me). Three boxes below the first (Written Articles). And everything was fine.

But then I made another one after the the three boxes and it is messing with the three boxes above.

For some reason it is really messing with the first of the three article boxes. It affects the width of this box.

If I comment out the last div they all adjust themselves to the width I want.

I can not figure out what is happening.

I will put the full HTML and CSS here so you can check it for yourselves and see the difference when you comment out the last div I used (div with a class of "g5").

**Basically I just want all three article boxes the same size, but the new div is messing with the width, and I can not figure out why.**

P.S. I am still new to CSS so my coding is not by any means elegant.

```css
body {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  font-family: Futura, Tahoma, 'Handlee', cursive;
  height: auto;
  magrin: 0;
}
.header {
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: auto;
  background-image: url("https://thebluestimes.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/blue-background-white-lines-texture-background-451_1.jpg")
}
#pictureSelf {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
#ownerName {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-text: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1f, 1fr, 1fr, 1fr, 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  width: auto;
}
.g1 {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 35px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  grid-row: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  color: hsl(216, 70%, 50%);
}
h1 span {
  border: 5px dashed hsl(216, 70%, 50%);
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
#aboutMe {
  padding: 10px;
}
quote {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.g2{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  width: auto;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes summary1 {
  from {
    height: 220px;

  }
  to {
    height: 350px;
  }
}
.g2:hover {
  animation-name: summary1;
  animation-play-state:running; 
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: height linear;
}
.g3{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 35px;
  height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.g3:hover {
  animation-name: summary1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state:running; 
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: linear;
}
.g4{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 35px;
  height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 5 / span 2;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.g4:hover {
  animation-name: summary1;
  animation-play-state:running; 
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: height linear;
 
}
#buis1 {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  heigth: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
#arT {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#arTLink {
  text-align: center;
}
a:link {
  color: hsl(216, 70%, 50%);
  border: 3px solid hsl(216, 70%, 50%);
  padding: 5px;
}
#arTLink a:hover {
  color: red;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
#arT2 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.g5 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  grid-row: 3;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
iframe {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 560px; 
  height: 315px; 
}
/*Media queries*/
@media (min-width:10px) and (max-width:500px) {
  .header {
    height: 20vh;
  }
    #pictureSelf {
    width: 20%;
    height: 70%;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  #ownerName {
   align-text: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: white;
  }
  h1 {
   font-size: 12px;
  }
  .g1 {
    width: auto;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  quote {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .g2 {
   grid-row: 3;
   width: auto;
   grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  }
  .g3 {
   grid-row: 4;
   grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  }
  .g4 {
   grid-row: 5;
   grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  }
  .g5 {
    grid-row: 6;
    width: auto;
    grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
</head>
<body>
  <!--Header-->
  <section class="header">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/13/21/07/user-33638_960_720.png" id="pictureSelf"></img>
  <p id="ownerName">Thomas Jefferson</p>
    </section>
  
  <!--Body-->
    <section class="container">
      
      <!--About Me-->
      <div class="g1">
        <h1><span>About Me</span></h1>
        <p id="aboutMe">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus nisi risus, non cursus elit egestas id. Integer quis euismod urna, quis blandit neque. Phasellus vel facilisis dolor. Integer et tincidunt nunc, sodales aliquam quam. Nulla sagittis quam sit amet dolor vulputate vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse vulputate justo non augue tincidunt, non vehicula augue cursus. Fusce tristique efficitur metus, ut tempus augue hendrerit eu. Nunc varius turpis quis elementum laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat! </p>
        <quote style="font-family:cursive;">"The greatest danger for most of us is not that our aim is too high and we miss it,<br/> but that it is too low and we reach it." - Michelangelo</quote>
      </div>
      
      
      <!--My Articles-->
      
      <div class="g2"><img src="https://www.summitfundingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/businessmen-shaking-hands-money-2-low_preview.jpeg" id="buis1"></img><p id="arT">Five Great Ways To Gain More Clients</p><p id="arTLink"><a href="www.google.com" >Read More</a></p><p id="arT2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus nisi risus, non cursus elit egestas id. Integer quis euismod urna, quis blandit neque. Phasellus vel facilisis dolor.</p></div>
  
      <div class="g3"><img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/04/happy-family-HD-picture-03.jpg" id="buis1"></img><p id="arT">Spending Time With Loved Ones.</p><p id="arTLink"><a href="www.google.com" >Read More</a></p><p id="arT2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus nisi risus, non cursus elit egestas id. Integer quis euismod urna, quis blandit neque. Phasellus vel facilisis dolor.</p></div>

      <div class="g4"><img src="https://www.itsdiscovery.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maxresdefault.jpg" id="buis1"></img><p id="arT">The Truth About Space.</p><p id="arTLink"><a href="www.google.com" >Read More</a></p><p id="arT2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus nisi risus, non cursus elit egestas id. Integer quis euismod urna, quis blandit neque. Phasellus vel facilisis dolor.</p></div>

<!--If you remove this div here the three div's above go back to intended width, each spread taking up equal space-->

      <div class="g5"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/go4wo4WenQQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

      <div class="g6"></div>
      <div class="g7"></div>
      <div class="g8"></div>
  </section>
    
    
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to add `max-width: 100%` to img tag? It prevent overflow at your g4 box

Comment: There is no such thing as a closing image tag </img>

Comment: Rafv: I have just tries adding the max-width but it made no difference. (I added it to all the img tags just to make sure). Thank you for the sugesstion but it is still the same.

Comment: Gerad: I know it does need a closing tag, but I just got into the habit of adding one when I began learning HTML and always forget to let it close itself lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of issues in your code. Using `<img></img>` is wrong, it should be only `<img>` and the `grid-template-columns` you are defining is wrong. No need comma between values.

```css
body {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  font-family: Futura, Tahoma, 'Handlee', cursive;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: auto;
  background-image: url("https://thebluestimes.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/blue-background-white-lines-texture-background-451_1.jpg")
}
#pictureSelf {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
#ownerName {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-text: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: auto;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  width: auto;
}
.g1 {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 35px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  grid-row: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  color: hsl(216, 70%, 50%);
}
h1 span {
  border: 5px dashed hsl(216, 70%, 50%);
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
#aboutMe {
  padding: 10px;
}
quote {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.g2{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  width: auto;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes summary1 {
  from {
    height: 220px;

  }
  to {
    height: 350px;
  }
}
.g2:hover {
  animation-name: summary1;
  animation-play-state:running; 
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: height linear;
}
.g3{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 35px;
  height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.g3:hover {
  animation-name: summary1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state:running; 
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: linear;
}
.g4{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 35px;
  height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 5 / span 2;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.g4:hover {
  animation-name: summary1;
  animation-play-state:running; 
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: height linear;
 
}
#buis1 {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  heigth: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
#arT {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#arTLink {
  text-align: center;
}
a:link {
  color: hsl(216, 70%, 50%);
  border: 3px solid hsl(216, 70%, 50%);
  padding: 5px;
}
#arTLink a:hover {
  color: red;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
#arT2 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.g5 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  grid-row: 3;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  border-radius: 25px;
}
iframe {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 560px; 
  height: 315px; 
}
/*Media queries*/
@media (min-width:10px) and (max-width:500px) {
  .header {
    height: 20vh;
  }
    #pictureSelf {
    width: 20%;
    height: 70%;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  #ownerName {
   align-text: center;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: white;
  }
  h1 {
   font-size: 12px;
  }
  .g1 {
    width: auto;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  quote {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .g2 {
   grid-row: 3;
   width: auto;
   grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  }
  .g3 {
   grid-row: 4;
   grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  }
  .g4 {
   grid-row: 5;
   grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  }
  .g5 {
    grid-row: 6;
    width: auto;
    grid-column: 1 / span 6;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Header-->
  <section class="header">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/13/21/07/user-33638_960_720.png" id="pictureSelf">
  <p id="ownerName">Thomas Jefferson</p>
    </section>
  
  <!--Body-->
    <section class="container">
      
      <!--About Me-->
      <div class="g1">
        <h1><span>About Me</span></h1>
        <p id="aboutMe">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus nisi risus, non cursus elit egestas id. Integer quis euismod urna, quis blandit neque. Phasellus vel facilisis dolor. Integer et tincidunt nunc, sodales aliquam quam. Nulla sagittis quam sit amet dolor vulputate vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse vulputate justo non augue tincidunt, non vehicula augue cursus. Fusce tristique efficitur metus, ut tempus augue hendrerit eu. Nunc varius turpis quis elementum laoreet. Aliquam erat volutpat! </p>
        <quote style="font-family:cursive;">"The greatest danger for most of us is not that our aim is too high and we miss it,<br/> but that it is too low and we reach it." - Michelangelo</quote>
      </div>
      
      
      <!--My Articles-->
      
      <div class="g2"><img src="https://www.summitfundingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/businessmen-shaking-hands-money-2-low_preview.jpeg" id="buis1"><p id="arT">Five Great Ways To Gain More Clients</p><p id="arTLink"><a href="www.google.com" >Read More</a></p><p id="arT2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus nisi risus, non cursus elit egestas id. Integer quis euismod urna, quis blandit neque. Phasellus vel facilisis dolor.</p></div>
  
      <div class="g3"><img src="https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/04/happy-family-HD-picture-03.jpg" id="buis1"><p id="arT">Spending Time With Loved Ones.</p><p id="arTLink"><a href="www.google.com" >Read More</a></p><p id="arT2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus nisi risus, non cursus elit egestas id. Integer quis euismod urna, quis blandit neque. Phasellus vel facilisis dolor.</p></div>

      <div class="g4"><img src="https://www.itsdiscovery.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/maxresdefault.jpg" id="buis1"><p id="arT">The Truth About Space.</p><p id="arTLink"><a href="www.google.com" >Read More</a></p><p id="arT2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus nisi risus, non cursus elit egestas id. Integer quis euismod urna, quis blandit neque. Phasellus vel facilisis dolor.</p></div>

<!--If you remove this div here the three div's above go back to intended width, each spread taking up equal space-->

      <div class="g5"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/go4wo4WenQQ" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

      <div class="g6"></div>
      <div class="g7"></div>
      <div class="g8"></div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D. I was trying to figure out this problem for nearly three hours before I asked the question here. Removing the commas solved the problem instantly. (I have only been coding CSS for three weeks now, and do seem to make these obvious mistakes lol. So I am grateful for any pointers you can give, and if there is anything else wrong with my code I would be very happy to hear what - or if there are ways I could simplify it I would love to hear how). Again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I noticed your main problem, you are defining the css properties of .g2, .g3, and .g4 twice.  Here's your css:

```
 .g4{
display: inline-block;
background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
border-radius: 35px;
height: 230px;
width: auto;
grid-row: 2;
grid-column: 5 / span 2;
overflow: hidden;
```

Here is your second: -Notice grid-column is different here

```
 .g4 {
 grid-row: 5;
 grid-column: 1 / span 6;
}
```

You are defining grid-column, and grid-row twice and they are different values

Comment: When I define them the second time, that is within the media queries, so they only take affect when the screen size changes (from computer to phone). The change in grid-row means on a phone they will not be beside each-other but underneath instead. And the grid-column helps to ensure they take up the full width of phones of different sizes. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Oh wow maybe when i answered this I was to tired to notice the media queries lol sorry

Comment: I know the feeling lol, I usually make random mistakes in my code when I am tired... If you look at the top of the css you can see I miss-spelt “margin”. :D